# Select elements from a list of of couples

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list which looks like

`a={{0., 2.}, {0.2, 1.96041}, {0.4, 1.9216}, {0.6, 1.88355}, {0.8, 1.8463},...}`

and I want to select all the n^th couples contained in another list,

`b={1, 3, 6, 7, 9,...}`

so in this case I need to extract the first, third... couples. How can I do?

Comment: Try `a[[b]]`?  ([Part](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html))

Comment: Yeah, that was it... Thanks!

Comment: @kglr to my taste, this is the best answer because it's simple

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`Extract`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html). Two pieces of code below should generate the same result.

```
Extract[a, #] & /@ b
Extract[a, {b}\[Transpose]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Following the lead from kglr's answer in the comments and noticing your `b` list:

Example:

```
alist = a = {{0., 2.}, {0.2, 1.96041}, {0.4, 1.9216}, {0.6, 
    1.88355}, {0.8, 1.8463}}
blist = {1, 7, 9, 2}
```

Notice that Parts 7,9 are not present and the following will complain.

```
alist[[blist]]
```

A slight improvement would be to filter the indices in `blist` that are (currently?) larger than the length of the `alist`.

```
Part[alist, Select[blist, # <= Length@alist & ]]
```

OR

```
alist[[Select[blist, # <= Length@alist & ]]]
```

It may or may not be important for your app. The ... and your current choice of indices for the `b` got me thinking.

> {{0., 2.}, {0.2, 1.96041}}